# Unable to redirect from login page to index page

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, code-signing

I'm facing with my login system. The code that I put is actually work, but only for the Sign Up. But when I tried to sign in it doesn't work.
Here is the **login.php**

```
<?php

    require 'DataBase.php';

    session_start();

    $db = new DataBase();

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST['sign-in'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if ($db->logIn("login", $username, $password)) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo "<script>location.href='index.php'</script>";
                exit;
            } else {
                $error = "Username or password is incorrect.";
                // Action if login fails
            }
        } elseif ($_POST['submit'] === 'Sign Up') {
            // User signup logic
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];


            $signupSuccess = $db->signUp("login", $username, $password, $email);

            if ($signupSuccess) {
                $successMessage = "Account created successfully. Please log in.";
            } else {
                $error = "Failed to create an account. Please try again.";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

```
<div class="login__forms">
                <form action="login.php" class="login__registre" id="login-in" method="post">
                    
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="login__input">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="login__input">
<button class="login__button" type="submit" name="sign-in" value="Sign In">Sign In</button>
```

both sign in and sign up can work correctly please ;((

Comment: Dump your $_POST, I bet you will understand what's wrong :)
I can see it, but it's better for yourself to start debugging
use : echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre'>

Comment: What does "*it doesn't work*" mean, exactly?  Are you getting errors?  Blank page?   BTW here's how to redirect in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the action in the login form. It can be edited into action="index.php" or action="welcome.php".